# RTC Jazz Build - Stale workspace

Tags: jenkins, rtc, build-definition

I work in a multi-person team with many developers delivering changes to the same stream. Each developer works on their own repository which flows into a **main** stream. I then have multiple build definitions for each of the environments we need to deploy to. Each build definition also has its own repository which flows to **main**

The problem we've noticed is that sometimes the build repository/workspace is not picking up the latest changes from each developer.

Can someone suggest a reason why this may be happening? I've checked that everyone is using the correct flow target, the team is distributed (China, Europe, US) but i'm guessing latency is hardly a concern.

Update: I was using the same build work-space across multiple build definitions which is not a recommendation. I changed this and have not had any issues since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latency shouldn't matter because the deliver operation is atomic, and your build monitors a stream.

So you need to check if the build definition is similar to one described in "[Continuous Integration with Rational Team Concert and Microsoft Visual Studio](https://jazz.net/library/article/518/)" (based on RTC4.x though), with, for instance, a periodic schedule:

[image: https://jazz.net/library/content/articles/rtc/3.0/continuous-integration-RTC-MVS/images/BuildDefSchedule.png]